# Fixed Div interacts with padding and text-align differently

Tags: jquery, css, layout

I have a parent `div` with a child.  The parent is the sticky, and the child is the `mainPicWrapper`

**CSS:**

```
.mainPicWrapper {
    border:1px solid black;
    padding-left:25px;
 }

 #sticky-div.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    border:0px;
 }
```

I have jQuery to remove the `.sticky class` on page load.

Then, when it scrolls down past the top of the `div`, it adds the `.sticky` class back, so the `div` stays at the top of the page while it scrolls down, which works fine.

But, if I remove the `padding-left:25px;` and replace it with `text-align:center;` then it doesn't work. With `text-align:center;`, when I scroll, the `div` suddenly jumps to the left back to zero.

*Why does `padding-left` stay applied to the sticky `div`, but `text-align:center;` does not?*

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/md7wewjm/3/) demo.

The problem with the `padding`, is there is actually an `img` in that `div`. And the image changes sizes frequently. If you scroll when having `padding`, thats fine, the images scrolls in the correct place. But using `padding` causes the multiple sized images to never load in the center of the `div`, which this is what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
.mainPicWrapper {
border:1px solid black;
text-align:center;
}

#sticky-div.sticky {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
border:0px;
right:7px;
width:70%;
}
.topRightMainContainer {
border:1px;
width:70%;
position:absolute;
right:7px;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/vd553kr4/)

Comment: That works.  Thank you so much. One day I'll understand how div and css layouts work.